# swift iOS play video from SCSwipeableFilterView

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter, recorder

I am currently using this pod, https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder, trying to allow the user to swipe through filters when watching a video in playback. The video plays fine until I add the filter code, then I get a blank screen. Can anyone tell me what the issue is. I have also set the view to a the SCSwipeableFilterView subclass in it's xib file. Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var filterView: SCSwipeableFilterView!






    if NSProcessInfo.processInfo().activeProcessorCount > 1 {
        self.customView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        var emptyFilter = SCFilter.emptyFilter()
        emptyFilter.name = "#nofilter"
        self.customView.filters = [emptyFilter, SCFilter(CIFilterName:"CIPhotoEffectNoir"), SCFilter(CIFilterName:"CIVignetteEffect"), SCFilter(CIFilterName:"CIPhotoEffect") ]
        self.newPlayer.SCImageView = self.customView
        self.customView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectedFilter", options: .New, context: nil)
    }
    else {
        var playerView = SCVideoPlayerView(player: newPlayer)
        playerView.playerLayer!.videoGravity = "ResizeAspectFill"
        playerView.frame = self.customView.frame
        playerView.autoresizingMask = self.customView.autoresizingMask
        self.customView.superview!.insertSubview(playerView, aboveSubview: self.customView)
        self.customView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Comment: Hey, Did you get the solution? I am facing the same please help!